# Compaq laptop won't power on

Tags: boot, compaq-laptop

I run a computer repair business and I received a Compaq C series laptop that doesn't boot on power up. I took [a video sample of the problem](http://img809.imageshack.us/i/zov.mp4/).

It just stays like that, in fact, I've left it on for 30 min.

Comment: We need more details, flag for reopening if post is improved.

Comment: I dont know how else to describe the problem. It just does what it does in the video. Stays at the screen forever.

Comment: Did you recently install software or new hardware?  Anything unusual lately? etc

Comment: I run a computer repair business and this is how I received this laptop.

Comment: can't really help you that much then...perhaps search around the site for similar questions related to nonbooting systems...

Comment: Try changing the HDD.

Comment: So you ask the client for more information, because this way you are unable to solve the problem.

Comment: The problem is that they dont know what they did and cannot explain it. @Studiohack could u please unlock it b/c I have found a solution?

Comment: reopened @ct6116...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours trying to go through the elimination process (RAM, GPU, Fans, etc), I removed the battery and tried running on AC power only, and it worked. It booted fine and I got into the OS. I didn't know that the battery could stop a computer from booting. I guess you do learn new things every day.